# Logging in with Safari behaves oddly

Tags: bug, login

Steps:

1. Visit a per-site meta. You will not be logged in, and automatic login doesn't fire.
2. Click the login button. You are brought to the login page of the parent site, automatic login fires, and you are redirected back to the page you were on on the meta site.
3. However, you still appear to be logged out, and need to refresh the page to see the logged-in view.

Perhaps Safari is doing some aggressive kind of caching on the page?

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2
```